# Two DIVs and one border

Tags: html

I have the following HTML with two DIVs, both are closed.

```html
<div>Hello,</div>
<div>My name is John</div>
```

I want the background of the second to be yellow. I can do that with the following html:

```html
<div>Hello,</div>
<div style="background-color: yellow">My name is John</div>
```

My question is, how can I set the style of the second DIV without using the style attribute on the second DIV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your structure. You can use `nth-child`:

```css
div:nth-child(2){background:yellow}
```

```html
<div>Hello,</div>
<div>My name is John</div>
```

Or adjacent sibling selector (`+`)

```css
div + div {background:yellow}
```

```html
<div>Hello,</div>
<div>My name is John</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the structure of your page, but this style defined into a stylesheet will work

```
div + div { 
   background: yellow
}
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/m9n3cs4u/